# ASP.NET core InvalidOperationException: 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext./

Tags: c#

I wanan save data on my app but i get

> InvalidOperationException, 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext.'

My code is below

```
public IActionResult Create(ProjectViewModel viewModel)
{
    ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(new Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>());
    dbContext.Project.Add(new Project()
    {
       ProjectName = viewModel.ProjectName,
       ProjectStart = viewModel.StartDate,
       ProjectEnd = viewModel.DeadLine,
       Priority = viewModel.Priority,
       Target = viewModel.Target,
       ProjectDescription = viewModel.Description,
       ProjectParts = viewModel.Amountofparts
    });
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
    return View(nameof(NewProject));
}
```

How can I fix it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe you need to add code, or it isn't explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add your dbContext to services as following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio 
Or you need to specific the connectionstring in your declare

Comment: Thank You, the controller save the data to the database, but  after dont go other page / return View(nameof(NewProject)); /